# WSO2 IS REST request XACML

Tags: rest, wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I find example usage API 
 https://localhost:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp
on 
https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/how-entitlement-management-works-with-rest-api-via-xacml-in-wso2-identity-server-5-3-0-7a60940d040c#.taxf6cvmx

Which request should I send to
 https://localhost:9443/api/identity/entitlement/decision/entitlements-all
To get all the access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following request:

```
    POST /api/identity/entitlement/decision/entitlements-all HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:9443
    Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
    Content-Type: application/json
    Accept: application/json
    {
        "identifier": "",
        "givenAttributes": []
    }
```